# Optimize SQL syntax with conditional WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to optimize the following parts of the stored procedure regarding the WHERE clause without using dynamic SQL? The only difference between the two alternatives is that if Admin = 1 then there shouldn't be any WHERE clause, otherwise it should be there.

```
DECLARE @Admin              bit,

/* Check if user is admin */
SET @Admin = (SELECT Admin FROM vwPROJECTUser WHERE UserID = @UserID)


/* Get results */   
IF @Admin = 1 
    BEGIN
        SELECT  ProjectID, 
                ProjectDescription                                              
        FROM vwPROJECT
        ORDER BY ProjectID
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT  ProjectID, 
                ProjectDescription                                              
        FROM vwPROJECT
        WHERE GroupID IN (SELECT GroupID FROM tblUserGroup WHERE UserID = @UserID)
        ORDER BY ProjectID
    END     
END
```

Comment: Can't you just add an `OR` to the second one and eliminate the first one?

`WHERE GroupID IN (SELECT GroupID FROM tblUserGroup WHERE UserID = @UserID) OR @Admin=1`

Comment: Sometimes the best solution is dynamic SQL (see [the kitchen sink](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/)). Why do you want to create arbitrary constraints that could eliminate the best solution? There are two variables issues you have to deal with here: (1) whether admin is 1 or not. (2) when the number of groups for the specific user has a lot of rows or not. Both of those variances aren't always dealt with in the same way. Also, [please always reference the schema](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion! I've tested and it looks like it returns the correct result.

Answer (score 1):

The comment from [Scott Hodgin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/60085/scott-hodgin) is a good choice.  Rewrite this as one query:

```
SELECT  ProjectID, 
        ProjectDescription                                              
FROM vwPROJECT
WHERE 
    GroupID IN (SELECT GroupID FROM tblUserGroup WHERE UserID = @UserID) 
    OR @Admin = 1;
```

This is extremely sensitive to parameter sniffing:

- the "admin" case needs to read the whole view
- the non-admin case could produce a variable number of rows depending on how many groups the user is in

If that becomes a problem, you could add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to the end of this query to resolve that (at the cost of increased CPU due to the recompiles). The CPU is likely not a big deal if this query isn't run extremely frequently - like many times per second.

Using dynamic SQL is a good option as well, and doesn't have the CPU issues of recompiling, although you've ruled that out so I'm just mentioning it for completeness.

Generally speaking, if branching like this in stored procedures doesn't work out well for performance, see [The Not Very Mighty IF Branch](https://erikdarlingdata.com/2019/02/the-not-very-mighty-if-branch/) for some of the problems you can run into.